# A uitextview that becomes first responder when tapped and detects links

Tags: ios, xcode4

I'm trying to make a UITextView that detects links AND becomes editable when a tap doesn't fall on a link.

The native iphone notes app exhibits this behavior, as does simplenote.

The closest solution I have found is outlined here: http://blog.stevex.net/2012/05/editable-uitextview-with-links/  Using this code:

```
// Add the tap gesture recogniser to the view.
- (void)configureTextView {
UITapGestureRecognizer *recognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self    action:@selector(textViewTapped:)];
textView.editable = NO;
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
[textView addGestureRecognizer:recognizer];
}

// Notification from the recogniser that the UITextView was tapped
- (void)textViewTapped:(UIGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
UITextView *textView = (UITextView *)recognizer.view;
textView.editable = YES;
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
}

// UITextViewDelegate method
- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView {
textView.editable = NO;
}
```

The problem with this solution is that it requires a long press to follow a link.

Comment: with the code that you mentioned above, does the textview giving the options to open url while holding the tap?

Comment: Yes. I think I need a different approach because all single taps are captured by the gesture recognizer with the approach above.